# Appcelerator Titanium Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, appcelerator

How can I get my keyboard to display when the text field gets focus?

Where do I start? None of my text fields work. The sample code below is for my Android app.

```
var txtEmail = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    width: 250,
    height: 35,
    top: 80,
    left: _MarginLeft,
    font:{fontSize:14,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    hintText: 'Please enter your email address',
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL
});
win.add(txtEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove/comment out the "keyboardType" line?

I usually start to comment out lines that aren't necessary for it to work. And once it starts working again, you have a pretty good idea that one of the extra things you've added are confusing it.

EDIT: Also, which emulator device are you using? All of the ones I've used don't have an onscreen keyboard. They just have one that is always there off to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
txtEmail.focus();
```

But I think it's automatic